# SVG.js animation of rotate and scale while moving along a path

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I have successfully gotten a rectangle to move along a path but have not been able to have it rotate and scale while staying on the path. The moment i specify the rotate and scale attributes it  wonders off the path. Here included are the relevant jsfiddle links of my examples ...

[working js fiddle with translate](https://jsfiddle.net/symbologysvg/k94c65mL/16/)

[not working js fiddle with path](https://jsfiddle.net/symbologysvg/kdwrL49b/4/)

The actual html for the 2 pages are as follows :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG.js</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #drawing{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }      
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onload();">
    <div id="drawing"></div>
    <script>
        function onload() {
            var timeline = new SVG.Timeline();                
            var draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').size(800, 800);
            var rect = draw.rect(50, 50).attr({fill: '#f06', id :'rect'});
            var line = draw.line(0, 0, 150, 150).stroke({width:2,color:'#ccc'});
            SVG('#rect').timeline(timeline).animate(5000,100,'absolute').rotate(45).animate(5000,100,'absolute').scale(0.4).animate(5000,100,'absolute').translate(150,150);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

and

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG.js</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #drawing{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }      
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onload();">
    <div id="drawing"></div>
    <script>
        function onload() {
            var draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').size(800, 800);
            var rect = draw.rect(50, 50).attr({fill: '#f06'});
            var path = draw.path("m 357.64532,453.84097 c 17.62007,8.02216 -2.12058,27.70935 -13.33334,29.28571 -30.3859,4.27185 -48.34602,-29.97426 -45.23807,-55.9524 5.5594,-46.46879 56.1311,-70.59787 98.57145,-61.19043 62.28294,13.8058 93.32728,82.57702 77.1428,141.19051 C 453.21679,585.29693 365.67122,623.42358 290.97859,600.26951 196.98554,571.13248 151.71003,464.56996 181.93108,373.84089 218.53281,263.95583 344.23687,211.49702 450.97875,248.84102 576.77037,292.84963 636.43303,437.76771 591.93099,560.50775 540.55162,702.21597 376.3736,769.09583 237.6452,717.41234 80.01319,658.68628 5.9069261,475.21736 64.788247,320.50751 130.84419,146.94643 333.62587,65.607117 504.31214,131.69819 693.80625,205.0718 782.38357,427.18225 709.07382,613.84113");
            var length = path.length();
            path.fill('none').stroke({width: 1, color: '#ccc'});
            rect.animate(5000,1000).ease('<>').during(function(eased){
                var p = path.pointAt(eased * length);
                rect.center(p.x, p.y);
            }).animate(5000,100,'absolute').rotate(45).animate(5000,100,'absolute').scale(0.5);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The help docs are not very helpful so i am asking here. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to rotate around the center of the element?

Comment: Yes, i want to rotate around the center and also scale from the center. Fuzzyma, i have been hoping for interaction with you, thnx.

Comment: Fuzzyma, are you still interested in assisting me with this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: This only works if you calculate the whole matrix in one go. So you cant have it start at different times. Well technically you can but then you have to calculate the timings as well

Comment: Fuzzyma, would it be able to then exclude and jut allow for the rotation round its center while moving. I can simply exclude the Scaling altogether. Sorry for the late response. Thanks Fuzzyma, if you could jut show me the inclusion of the rotation implementation.

Comment: Its the same problem. If it doesnt animate all at the same time it becomes very complicated

Comment: So the rotation must start and occur for the same time when moving along a path. That is fine then, I am creating an animation app that uses SVG.JS for all its animation so i set the requirement, so then that can just be reinforced in the UI. Can you make the necessary adjustments to accommodate for the rotate around center while moving along a path. MUCH APPRECIATED.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/omx9vs14/

Comment: Thanks, works wonderfully to decrease the scale. What is the formula to increase the scale. I know ease always goes from 0 to 1. How would the increase calculation be calculated if you go to scale of 1.5

Comment: Get a piece of paper and do the math for yourself. If you can program, you certainly can do a bit of algebra as well

Comment: The algebra i worked out for both are : ((scale - 1) * eased) + 1 AND scale * (1 - eased) + scale